Importing dataset from Google Sheets to MySQL sever with python
I watched a Youtube video about importing dataset from Google Sheets to a SQL sever. However, the tutorial used Microsoft SQL while I use MySQL. So I can't use the same pushing code like the tutorial. I tried to find some documents, and inspect MySQL Workbench but it still didn't work. Is there a way to find the driver and sever name of MySQL sever?
Here's my code that I tried:
DRIVER_NAME = 'MySQL'
SEVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1'
DATABASE_NAME = 'Prototype'

And here is my full code:
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc as odbc

from Google import Create_Service #nhập Create_service từ google

"""
Getting Dataset from Google Sheets 
"""

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

google_sheets_id = '1G7hwo9YJXuDZIUeOQmxxqrsEMv4QvNd11K15Ng4zjhA'

response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId = google_sheets_id,
    majorDimension = 'ROWS',
    range = 'Lớp 12'
).execute()

rows = response['values'][1:]

"""
Push Dataset to SQL sever (database system)
"""
DRIVER_NAME = 'MySQL'
SEVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1'
DATABASE_NAME = 'Prototype'

def connection_stirng(driver_name, sever_name, database_name):
    # uid = <username>;
    # pwd = <password>;
    conn_string = f"""
        DRIVER = {{{driver_name}}};
        SEVER = {sever_name};
        DATABASE = {database_name};
        Trust_Connection = yes; 
    """
    return conn_string

#connection object creation
try:
    conn = odbc.connect(connection_stirng(DRIVER_NAME, SEVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME))
    
    print('Connection created')
except odbc.DatabaseError as e:
    print('DatabaseError:')
    print(str(e.value[1]))
except odbc.Error as e:
    print('Connection Error')
    print(str(e.value[1]))
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_insert = """
        INSERT INTO Stockdata
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    """
    try:
        cursor.executemany(sql_insert, rows)
        cursor.commit()
        print('Data import complete')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e.value[1]))
        cursor.rollback()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

Here's my VS code response when I run it:
sheets v4 service created successfully.
Connection Error:
[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified


have you tried doing this first pip install mysql-connector-python

I have just tried it but I think my driver and sever name was wrong cuz it still gave the same response

import mysql.connector as mysql  # Changed from pypyodbc to mysql.connector

Issues

change import mysql.connector as mysql  # <- change from pypyodbc to mysql.connector
create a function for your MSQL connection

def create_mysql_connection(sever_name, database_name, user, password):
    return mysql.connect(  # `mysql.connect` to establish a connection
        host=sever_name,
        database=database_name,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )

conn = create_mysql_connection(SEVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, USER, PASSWORD)
if conn.is_connected():  
   print('conn established')


Thank you! it worked, though some other errors occured but i'll try to fix it

@Henry No worries, once you can't make sense of the error just put it on stackoverflow or put it on here. I or someone would always help.
